# TTS Android removing addSpeech item?

Tags: android

I have used

```
mTts.addSpeech(text, filename.getAbsolutePath() );
```

to map an audio file to a particular string of text.

The problem is that if the used deletes the file, which is possible/likely in my case, I need to remove the addSpeech  mapping from mTts (using removeSpeech() which does not exist) so that it reverts to computerised voice.

is this possible?

This is the stack trace I am getting after I add a file using addSpeech, then remove the file and attempt to speak again.

```
12-17 15:41:45.016: ERROR/MediaPlayer(361): error (1, -2147483648)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361): create failed:
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:611)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:588)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.tts.TtsService.processSpeechQueue(TtsService.java:1098)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.tts.TtsService.speak(TtsService.java:507)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.tts.TtsService.access$1900(TtsService.java:58)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.tts.TtsService$1.speak(TtsService.java:1256)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.speech.tts.ITts$Stub.onTransact(ITts.java:86)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
12-17 15:41:45.056: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(361):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

From API:

*public int addSpeech (String text, String filename)*

Adds a mapping between a string of text and a sound file. Using this, it is possible to add custom pronounciations for a string of text. After a call to this method, subsequent calls to

*speak(String, int, HashMap)*

***will play the specified sound resource if it is available, or synthesize the text it is missing.***

so, it's possible

I write simple method. It works.

```
private void speak(String text) {
    if(text != null) {
        HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "end of message - "+text);
        mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the stack trace I am getting when I do this to my question

Comment: It's good tutorial about TTS: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html